# menu python command line

Tags: python, command-line, menu

I have this menu. It load dynamically a class and call a method. Everything is fine but the method print hello just when I write 'exit'. Any suggestion is welcome?

```
class ClassA(object):
    def main(self):
        libs = self.directory()
        print '***************************************************'
        print '* Menu'
        for item in libs :
          print '** ' + item 
        print '***************************************************'

        while True:
            module_name = raw_input(">>> ")

            if module_name != "":
                if module_name == 'exit':
                  break 
                elif module_name in libs:  
                  lib = __import__(module_name)
                  class_ = getattr(lib, module_name)
                  theclass = class_()
                  theclass.myfunction() 
                  break   
                else:
                  print 'Module does not exist'
```

Class B

```
class ClassB(object):
    def myfunction(self):
        print 'hello'
```

Comment: [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/goxbC2). "Hello" is not printed when I type "exit". Please provide a [short, self-contained, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem, including the exact input you give, the exact output you receive, and the exact output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some *major* modifications to your code, this might be what you want:

```
import glob

class ClassB():
    def myfunction(self):
        print 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    libs = [item[:-3] for item in glob.glob("*.py")]
    print '***************************************************'
    print '* Menu'
    for item in libs :
      print '** ' + item
    print '***************************************************'

    while True:
        module_name = raw_input(">>> ")
        if module_name != "":
            if module_name == 'exit':
              break 
            if module_name in libs: 
              lib = __import__(module_name)
              class_ = getattr(lib, 'ClassB')
              theclass = class_()
              theclass.myfunction() 
              break   
            else:
              print 'Module does not exist'
```

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to mark this question as the correct answer ;)